# Why use subjunctive mood in 'all the force would be transferred back to the ship'?

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, subjunctive-mood, will-would, future-in-past

When reading a discussion about whether the Titanic could have avoided sinking, I saw a sentence that puzzled me a lot, as following:

> – it would probably have survived. [When a ship hits an iceberg head on, all the force would be transferred back to the ship], so it wouldn’t have ripped open, but crumpled round, so only 2-3 compartments would have been breached.

My question lies in this part (as included in the square bracket):  'When a ship hits an iceberg head on, all the force would be transferred back to the ship.'

I have no question with the 'when' clause, but the latter clause: 'all the force would be transferred back to the ship'. This part seems to be in subjunctive mood. But why is it put in subjunctive mood? Is it unreal? Isn't it a fact that 'When a ship hits an iceberg head on, all the force will be transferred back to the ship'? I wonder why it has to be 'all the force would be transferred...'. What's implied of the author's intention in using 'would' instead of 'will'.

As far as I know, subjunctive mood can indicate 'unreal, imagined, unlikely things, hypothesis, and in some cases, to show politeness, as in 'would you do...'. This mood can also be a 'soft voice' and make a statement sound less assertive as in 'I would argue...'. So what exactly is implied by that sentence?

Comment: There is no subjunctive mood here, so your question in incredibly confusing. There is no morphological inflection of the verb the way there arguably is in *If only it were so!* and in *Be it ever so humble*. **Prefixing an infinitive with a modal verb doth no subjunctive make.**

Comment: Were a ship to hit an iceberg head on, all the force would be transferred back to the ship ....

Comment: I agree with the first comment that there is no subjunctive clause in your example. I do agree with you, however, that "would" is inappropriate -- the verb "be" is required, as in "when a ship hits an iceberg head on, all the force **is** transferred back to the ship".

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. If it's not subjuntive, what's the implied meaning in using 'all the forces would be transferred back...' instead of 'all the forces will be transferred back...'?

Comment: Were a ship to hit an iceberg head on, all the force would be transferred back to the ship ....This sentence makes good sense to me. It's the right form to imagine a scenario

Comment: @Eglantine Re. you first question: we use preterite "would" in **remote** conditionals, and present tense "will" in **open** conditionals. Re. your second question: yes, it's a remote conditional, so "would" is fine. Note that remote conditionals are those where the condition is not fulfilled or presented as a relatively remote possibility. Open conditionals are those that are neutral as to whether the condition is or will be met.

Comment: @BillJ Many thanks. Your answer is really helpful because it is your key words 'remote conditional and open conditional' that helps me get a useful video which is based on Cambridge-sourced reference.

Comment: @BillJ,many thanks. Your answer is very helpful, and with your key words, the remote conditional and the open conditional, I've got a useful video that I think clarifies my confusion. Really have learned something. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bastardised sentence: the problem is with *hits,* which doesn't go with *would be* or *would have*. *Would be* certainly is not subjunctive (which is either *be* or *were* for the verb *to be*).

Your sentence, talking about a general ship hitting an iceberg, could start "When a ship hits an iceberg..." but should then continue in the present tense (albeit with conditionals):

> When a ship hits an iceberg head on, all the force is transferred back to the ship, so it wouldn’t be ripped open, but crumpled round, and only 2–3 compartments would be breached.

The subjunctive mood generally expresses intention, suggestion or desire: "We suggest **she visit** the doctor," or in your sentence "I ask that all **the force be transferred** back to the ship."